# Add style to multiple element on hover - scss

Tags: css, sass

I currently have this code which turns the footer titles and subtitle white when a footer cell is hovered over, and it works:

```
.footer-cell {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    height: 160px;

    &:hover .footer-title {  // footer-title line
        color: white;
    }

    &:hover .footer-subtitle {  // footer-subtitle line
        color: white;
    }
}
```

Is there any way that I can combine the footer-title line and the footer-subtitle line so I dont have duplicate code?  I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
.footer-cell {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    height: 160px;

    &:hover .footer-title, .footer-subtitle {
        color: white;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap the selectors in the `:hover` class:

```
.footer-cell {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    height: 160px;

    &:hover{ 
        .footer-title, .footer-subtitle {
           color: white;
        }
    }
}
```

[Compiles to this](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/7f963052f214303b90400899e5943c03)